# Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, insert

Estoy tratando de realizar un insert en una tabla de mi bbdd y me lanza el error 1136.

Esta la instrucción de creación de la tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esta es mi tabla:

[image]

Estoy intentando insertar estos valores:

`insert into Prueba_Ivan.mag_usuarios (xusuario_id, xempresa_id, xnombre, xpassword, xcliente_id, xlocal_cob_id, xlocal_env_id, xlocal_fact_id, xgrupo, xnif) values ('1', NULL, 'Nombre1','pass1',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);`

He visto en posts similares que este error se debe a que no se corresponden el nº de atributos y el de valores a introducir, pero en mi caso tengo el mismo número (10).

No se si el error se debe a que no he introducido valores en las tablas que tienen relación con mis claves foraneas.

Alguno podría ayudarme a encontrar el error y solucionarlo?

Muchas gracias!! Un saludo.

Comment: Podrías agregar el error que te tira más allá del número?

Comment: @andres está en el título de la pregunta: Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: perdón, no me di cuenta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu PK `xusuario_id` es autoincremental? De ser así tenés que omitir el campo.
Lo correcto en tu caso sería:

```
insert into Prueba_Ivan.mag_usuarios
    (xempresa_id, xnombre, xpassword, xcliente_id, xlocal_cob_id, xlocal_env_id, xlocal_fact_id, xgrupo, xnif) 
values 
    (NULL, 'Nombre1','pass1',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

Esto es porque el `xusuario_id` se genera sólo y estas queriendo hacer un `insert` por lo que el DBMS no espera que le especifiques la PK ya que la genera automaticamente incrementando el último id (de la mano de esto: con tu forma de plantearlo, por cada inserción deberías ir a buscar a la base el ultimo id para generar uno nuevo). El tipo de query que compartiste si te serviría para un `update` para cuando quieras cambiar el valor de la PK y esto funcionará siempre y cuando no se repita.

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido solucionarlo, resulta que el error no era por la instrucción del insert, si no que se debía a un trigger que tenía asociado a la tabla y en el que no cumplía los requisitos de tener el mismo número de atributos y de datos a insertar.

Gracias por vuestra ayuda!!!

Comment: Genial, podrías marcar como resulta la pregunta? Podes hacerlo dandole un check a tu respuesta

Comment: Claro que si, muchas gracias por la ayuda!!!